# VBA code should also read the extension of file before copying

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

I am working on the code which successfully copies the file (based on partial name list) from one folder to another. However i just would like to request if there is any possible way where the code can also read the extension of file before copy. For example column A contains the name of files and Column Column B contains extensions of each file, therefore the code should first read the file name and then extensions and if it matches then it should copy otherwise skips. I have the files with the following extension.

XML
PDF
TXT
ZIP
RAR
PDF

also the code i have is mentioned below

```
Sub moveFilesFromListPartial()
    
    Const sPath As String = "E:\Uploading\Source"
    Const dPath As String = "E:\Uploading\Destination\Destination_2\!Destination_3"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As String = "B"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet2
    
    ' Calculate the last row,
    ' i.e. the row containing the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
                
    ' Validate the last row.
    If lRow < fRow Then
        MsgBox "No data in column range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Early Binding - needs a reference
    ' to 'Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime' (has intelli-sense)
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    ' Late Binding - needs no reference (no intelli-sense)
    'Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Validate the source folder path.
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = sPath
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The source folder path '" & sFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Validate the destination folder path.
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = dPath
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(dFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The destination folder path '" & dFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim r As Long ' current row in worksheet column
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sPartialFileName As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim sYesCount As Long ' source file moved
    Dim sNoCount As Long ' source file not found
    Dim dYesCount As Long ' source file exists in destination folder
    Dim BlanksCount As Long ' blank cell
    
For r = fRow To lRow

    sPartialFileName = CStr(ws.Cells(r, Col).Value)

    If Len(sPartialFileName) > 3 Then ' the cell is not blank

        ' 'Begins with' sPartialFileName

        sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sPartialFileName & "*")

        ' or instead, 'Contains' sPartialFileName

        'sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*" & sPartialFileName & "*")

        Do While sFileName <> ""

            If Len(sFileName) > 3 Then ' source file found

                sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName

                dFilePath = dFolderPath & sFileName

                If Not fso.FileExists(dFilePath) Then ' the source file...

                    fso.CopyFile sFilePath, dFilePath ' ... doesn't exist...

                    sYesCount = sYesCount + 1 ' ... in the destination

                Else ' the source file exists in the destination folder

                    dYesCount = dYesCount + 1

                End If

            Else ' the source file doesn't exist

                sNoCount = sNoCount + 1
            End If
            sFileName = Dir
        Loop
    Else ' the cell is blank
        BlanksCount = BlanksCount + 1
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

I will be really thankful

Comment: Check [GetExtensionName method](https://learn.microsoft.com/eN-Us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getextensionname-method) to get the extension of a file and check it with yours.

Comment: You said that the file name is in A:A and extension in B:B, but your code iterates only in B:B... Do you want changing the whole solution as you are requiring now, or is it a mistake?

Comment: it is a mistake, the file names will be in Column A:A and file extensions can be in Column B:B

Comment: the reason for requesting for extensions is because at times i received same file names with different formats so after the amendments i can update my sheet to copy the required file with required extension

Comment: Like I said, your code iterates only on column B:B. Anyhow, if you change `Const Col As String = "A"` and create a new variable `Dim ext as String` Then using `ext = CStr(ws.Cells(r, 2).Value)` followed by `sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sPartialFileName & "*" & ext)` you will solve the problem. Extension (`ext`) in the cell value (B:B) is good to also contain the dot. I mean: `.pdf`, `.zip`, `.txt` etc.

Comment: i will add the dot with the extensions in Column B e.g. .xml .pdf Dear @FaneDuru is it possible if you could please update  your suggestion in the code as well, i will be thankful

Comment: OK, I will do it but not right now. I have something urgent to finish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next updated code. It uses my suggestion from my above comment. It works only **if the file partial name exists in "A:A" column and extension in "B:B"**:

```
Sub moveFilesFromListPartial()
    Const sPath As String = "E:\Uploading\Source"
    Const dPath As String = "E:\Uploading\Destination\Destination_2\!Destination_3"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As String = "A", colExt As String = "B"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet2
    
    ' Calculate the last row,
    ' i.e. the row containing the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, Col).End(xlUp).row
                
    ' Validate the last row.
    If lRow < fRow Then
        MsgBox "No data in column range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Early Binding - needs a reference
    ' to 'Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime' (has intelli-sense)
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    ' Late Binding - needs no reference (no intelli-sense)
    'Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Validate the source folder path.
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = sPath
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The source folder path '" & sFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Validate the destination folder path.
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = dPath
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(dFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The destination folder path '" & dFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim r As Long ' current row in worksheet column
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sPartialFileName As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim sYesCount As Long ' source file moved
    Dim sNoCount As Long ' source file not found
    Dim dYesCount As Long ' source file exists in destination folder
    Dim BlanksCount As Long ' blank cell
    Dim sExt As String    'extension (dot inclusive)
    
For r = fRow To lRow

    sPartialFileName = CStr(ws.cells(r, Col).Value)
    sExt = CStr(ws.cells(r, colExt).Value)
    
    If Len(sPartialFileName) > 3 Then ' the cell is not blank

        ' 'Begins with' sPartialFileName

        sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sPartialFileName & "*" & sExt)

        Do While sFileName <> ""

            If Len(sFileName) > 3 Then ' source file found

                sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName

                dFilePath = dFolderPath & sFileName

                If Not fso.FileExists(dFilePath) Then ' the source file...

                    fso.CopyFile sFilePath, dFilePath ' ... doesn't exist...

                    sYesCount = sYesCount + 1 ' ... in the destination

                Else ' the source file exists in the destination folder

                    dYesCount = dYesCount + 1

                End If

            Else ' the source file doesn't exist

                sNoCount = sNoCount + 1
            End If
            sFileName = Dir
        Loop
    Else ' the cell is blank
        BlanksCount = BlanksCount + 1
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Dear @Faneduru i will definitely test and will update you. thanks

Comment: Wonderful!! Working exactly, Bundle of thanks